# Movie that reminds of "The Stuff", but is like more mutation-like..?

Tags: story-identification, horror

When I was a bit younger I watched an old 80's movie on Showtime that still stick to my mind to this day.

- There is a poison or diseases that cause heavy mutation and death.
- Most of it is taking place in a lab or office like place.
- There is a scene where a person's tongue starts to "push" its way out of his/her's mouth and is killing him/her.

In my hunt I did come over across the movie "[The Stuff](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090094/)" hoping it was it, but sadly no. It did strongly reminded me of it though.
"edit" I mean in the something ingested i guess. It's just one of the parts i'm not sure about. but one thing i do remember is that its not like a killer goo or a monster.

Comment: In what sense was it killing him? Strangling him, choking him?

Comment: i think choking him, but as in filling the entire mouth and blocking it. At least that's what i remember.

Comment: Just to ask the obvious question: have you checked out the 80's version of The Blob?

Comment: yeah, sorry that's not it, well saying its like the stuff, i guess i mean in the something ingested i guess. It's just one of the parts i'm not sure about. but one thing i do remember is that its not like a killer goo or a monster.